# Order the variable of the Y axis in "geom_title"

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap, geom-tile

**Question: I want order the variable in Y axis based on the number of "Zero". Other than, what if I have 20 or more variable?**

my data is simple and show in the fig:

[image]

I use ggplot2 to draw that, here is my code:

```
ggplot(data, aes(year, factor(name))) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill =value),colour = "white") +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette="Spectral",name="value") +
  coord_fixed(ratio=1)+
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0))+
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0), 
                 breaks=seq(1990, 2022, by=1)) +

theme_bw()
```

run the code:
[image]

**dput(data)** can show all the structure of data. The information display here:

```
structure(list(year = c(1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 
2005, 2006, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 
1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006), name = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), levels = c("c", "b", 
"a"), class = "factor"), value = c(0, 0, 0, 0.346651040983634, 
0.575355736998419, 0.258813293790067, 0.996722462580923, 0.634714417365377, 
0.574420498061632, 0, 0.2, 0.244170435115193, 0.614290360870049, 
0.886645071330728, 0.902835323742732, 0.0956880849086607, 0.229170033665038, 
0.4679607332906, 0, 0, 0.8, 0.3, 0.0223354578076282, 0.957371777609129, 
0.619967737221035, 0.79910708466687, 0.623430562124169)), row.names = c(NA, 
27L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Could you please add the output of `dput(data)`?

Comment: That code does not yield that plot, are you sure you posted the correct code?

Comment: @T. C. Nobel  I try this code again. It is possible that the code is indented incorrectly. I edited it and it works.